# Are sun-synchronous orbits possible around any body?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, sun-synchronous

Sun-synchronous orbits are popular around Earth, and the [Mars Reconnaisance Orbiter](http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/mro/mission/timeline/mtscienceops/scienceopssciorbit/) uses one as well (so I think [Wikipedias definition as a geocentric orbit is wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sun-synchronous_orbit&qoldid=564797014)).  Considering that probably any rotating body has some oblateness, is a sun-synchronous orbit always possible, or are there some fundamental limitations that make sun-synchronous orbits impossible around certain planets, minor planets, moons, or other bodies in the solar system?

(A heliocentric orbit is of course a special case)

Answer (score 7):

No. First, the matter of oblateness which introduces the necessary precession. In some cases it will force the sun-synchronous orbit altitude below the body's surface (obviously impossible). In other cases other bodies will disturb the orbital motion too strongly, destabilizing the orbit.

Comment: There is never a *perfect* sun-synchronous orbit. One around the Earth will be disturbed by the Moon, too, although much less.

Comment: @ernestopheles: Agreed, but one around Venus will only be affected by other planets and possibly stray meteors and the likes.

Comment: I kind of agree, but for the fun of this argument, even Venus has an [inhomogeneous gravity field](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/mgn_gravity.jpg). Besides, just like Earth, it is not a sphere :-)

Comment: @ernestopheles There are no spheres.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. The Moon's small oblateness (less than a tenth that of the Earth in terms of $J_2$) and small mass (0.0123 that of the Earth) mean that a sun-synchronous orbit about the Moon would have to be orbiting inside the Moon.

Comment: @DavidHammen That should be an answer

Comment: Looks good! @DavidHammen the answer has been edited.

Comment: What about a binary star system?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Depends on the type of system, take Alpha Centauri AB - Proxima Centauri style triple system, where A,B orbit each other very close to barycenter and C (Proxima) is 13,000 AU away. Is the planet's orbit around the barycenter, or around one of the constituents? In the former case, it could be only synchronous to barycenter. In the latter, the other star will be destabilizing but all single-star rules apply. Or you could go synchronous to a *different star*, there's not much problem with a Proxima's planet's satellite to be synchronous to Alpha AB.

Comment: "Earth, it is not a sphere" - Earth is more spherical than snooker's ball

Answer (score 0):

No, it exist only at that bodies which Hill's Sphere radius is greater than sun-synchronous orbit height. In the other case you will need to spend the fuel to correct orbit perturbations.