# Is a lunar Sun-synchronous orbit possible at the "frozen" inclination of 86°?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, orbit, orbital-maneuver, trajectory

I have been considering if it would be possible to place a satellite in a Sun-synchronous orbit in one of the lunar frozen orbits at 86°. According to NASA scientists there are four inclinations for orbits wherein a satellite can stay in low lunar orbit indefinitely:

> "There are actually a number of 'frozen orbits' where a spacecraft can stay in a low lunar orbit indefinitely. They occur at four inclinations: 27º, 50º, 76º, and 86º"—the last one being nearly over the lunar poles.

-http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2006/06nov_loworbit/

My question is whether precession would still be possible in a frozen orbit. An orbit over the lunar poles could potentially allow a continuous supply of solar energy. I believe this orbit might be possible with zero eccentricity at a bit above 200 km altitude. This is provided that the satellite can remain in the frozen orbit and would still precess due to the oblateness of the moon. However I am unsure if there might be some reason that this kind of orbital precession might not work as well since I am not very familiar with frozen orbits. I'm also unaware how long it might take for the Earth to perturb this orbit. Is a lunar Sun-synchronous orbit possible when using a frozen orbit?

I also did find an interesting way of reaching a lunar polar orbit on Hop's blog (who had directed me to this site):
http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2013/08/lunar-ice-vs-neo-ice.html

Kind regards,

Peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Moon's $J_2$ of $2.0330530\times 10^{-4}$ gives only very low, not very inclined retrograde orbits.  The inclinations start at 130° at a zero altitude orbit, and go up to 180° at about 200 km altitude.  See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5314/265) for more details.

Comment: Could Lunar slight orbital eccentricity be used to achieve orbital precession required? Perhaps in higher Lunar orbits?

Comment: No.  You need to keep periapsis above the surface.  Increasing $e$ also requires you to increase $a$ to hold periapsis.  Overall, the rotation rate of the node goes down as you increase eccentricity.

Comment: That makes sense, Mark. I think I was using the wrong J2 value in my calculations. Is the one listed in this chart some other coefficient? http://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/zonalharmonicgravitymodel.html

Comment: Ack.  No, _I_ was using the wrong $J_2$ value!  I just checked and the number I found was from a table of normalized coefficients, instead of unnormalized.  The value you found is the right one to use.  The most recent estimate is $2.0330530\times 10^{-4}$.  I will update the answer.

Comment: Er. For the less mathematically inclined such as I ... is answer to the question then a 'No'?

Comment: @Everyone While there is barely a Sun-synchronous orbit possible at very low altitude and very high inclination (well past 130° for practicality), those orbits are always eclipsed - they go behind the Moon every 2 hours and experience darkness. Since the question asks about solar power and the nearly-polar 86° "frozen" orbit, the answer seems to be, sadly, and as you have proposed, "No".