# Local Time drift of Sun synchronous orbit

Tags: orbit, sun-synchronous

How does **inclination** perturbation affect drift in **local time** of a sun synchronous orbit? e.g orbit with inclination of 98 degrees and height 600km with local time 10:30

Comment: [This answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/5314/265) has the equation relating inclination to the orbit plane rotation rate. The extent to which the orbit plane rotation period is not one year is the local time drift.

Comment: I disagree that this is an "unclear" question. I think it's clear and answerable (using the equations from Mark's link) even with just the first sentence.